Can an experiment be started with conditional approval from the IRB of record?
We intend to perform an experiment with human subjects. As part of it, teams will answer questionnaires on technical subjects like math, work in teams to develop some technical documents on algorithms and answer a questionnaire on their team dynamics (team cohesion, their skill levels, etc.,) while working together.
The IRB is conditionally approved by the IRB of record and the only pending is obtaining a reliance agreement with PI's university. Conditional approval was provided for all research interventions, questionnaires, data storage and risks discussed. The reliance agreement states that we are the IRB of record, only final results will be shared with the PI and nothing else (such as the participants' private data) will be not shared with them.
Can we run the experiment while we wait for the reliance agreement and full approval?
If we do, what sort of penalty can be expected?

Sounds like a question for the IRB.

Out of curiosity, what action would you take based on the guidance of folks on the internet, outside of the advice to ask the board?

For the last part, see: What possible consequences could one face for not getting IRB approval for federally-funded research?

Do not rely on anyone else's guidance on this but your own IRB. The risk of consequences for your study if you get it wrong cannot be overstated.
Ask your IRB.
Otherwise, assume "conditional" has its normal meaning: when something is conditionally approved, it's not approved yet.

The answer to IRB questions is always "Ask your IRB."
Not even "Ask your advisor, he or she should know."  I saw a fellow student nearly shredded because his advisor steered him very very wrong.  And that was a simple, clear-cut situation that everyone else who ever heard about it asked, "What were they thinking?!" at an R1 institute known for having a very sensitive IRB.
If that situation could go wrong, any situation can go wrong.
Always ask your IRB.
